# Error code: InvalidIntentSamplePhraseSlot -

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I got the error code `Error code: InvalidIntentSamplePhraseSlot` when I built the model using the new skills console.
The full error message is

```
Sample utterance "AddBookmarkIntent i am at {pageno} of {mybook}" in intent "AddBookmarkIntent" cannot include both a phrase slot and another intent slot. Error code: InvalidIntentSamplePhraseSlot -
```

where `{pageno}` is `AMAZON.NUMBER` and `{mybook}` is `AMAZON.SearchQuery`

What is the error about and how can I solve it?

*edit*: add the JSON for the intent

```
{
    "name": "AddBookmarkIntent",
    "slots": [
        {
            "name": "mybook",
            "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery"
        },
        {
            "name": "pageno",
            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        }
    ],
    "samples": [
        "i am at {pageno} of the book {mybook}",
        "save page {pageno} to the book {mybook}",
        "save page {pageno} to {mybook}",
        "i am at {pageno} of {mybook}"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not allowed to have a slot of the type `AMAZON.SearchQuery` in the same *Utterance* with another slot, in your case `AMAZON.NUMBER`.

Mark one of the slots as required and ask for them separately.

A little example:

Create the Intent put in the utterances and slots:

```
"intents": [
    {
      "name": "AddBookmarkIntent",
      "samples": [
        "I am at {pageno}"
      ],
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "mybook",
          "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery",
          "samples": [
            "For {mybook}"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "pageno",
          "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Mark the specific slot as required so Alexa will automatically ask for it:

```
"dialog": {
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": "AddBookmarkIntent",
      "confirmationRequired": false,
      "prompts": {},
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "mybook",
          "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery",
          "elicitationRequired": true,
          "confirmationRequired": false,
          "prompts": {
            "elicitation": "Elicit.Intent-AddBookmarkIntent.IntentSlot-mybook"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and create the prompts to ask for the slot:

```
"prompts": [
  {
    "id": "Elicit.Intent-AddBookmarkIntent.IntentSlot-mybook",
    "variations": [
      {
        "type": "PlainText",
        "value": "For which book you like to save the page?"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is probably much easier with the skill builder BETA and not its editor because it will automatically create the JSON in the background.

Comment: This makes much sense to me. Thank you very much. I just wonder if this a kind of bug or they do this for a purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that you have an Intent name in your Sample Utterance where it should only have Slots and it looks like you do.

```
"AddBookmarkIntent i am at {pageno} of {mybook}"
```

"AddBookmarkIntent" shouldn't actually be inside of the utterance. So turn your utterance into:

```
"i am at {pageno} of {mybook}"
```

---

I know that some of the documents show an example of the sample utterances with the Intent Name first, [such as here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/define-the-interaction-model-in-json-and-text.html#cert-sample-utterances).  But that has a big warning near the top:
[image]
So you have to be careful about which documents you read and follow based on which way you are building your Alexa Skill.
[Follow this if you are using the Skill Builder.](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/use-the-skill-builder-beta-to-define-intents-slots-and-dialogs.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering @Jay. However I don have AddBookmarkIntent in my utterance. Please see my update post for my JSON.

Comment: Ok thanks, yeah the updated JSON looks good to me. And you are not using "mybook" or "pageno" elsewhere as an intent name?

Comment: No, I don't. The problem seems to be from this intent.

Answer (score 1):

It unfortunately seems like an utterance can only reference 1 "Phrase" slot type.

For your specific case, it does look like there is now a non-phrase slot type `AMAZON.Book` in public beta; if you use that instead of `AMAZON.SearchQuery` it might work?

Src: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html